# Using Bloomberg BDH formula for several cells in a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, bloomberg

Do you think it is possible to use the BDH formula but instead of using the name of one security we use the information within the cells for instance (assume that on the column A you have the ISIN of the securities and I want the price on column C at a certain date, date available in the column B):

```
for I = 1 to 10 

  cells(i+1,3) = BDH(cells(i+1,1),"PX_LAST", cells(i+1,3), cells(I+1,3), "Period, Dates", "M,H") 

next I
```

Comment: Of course it is possible, if you create a UDF, perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236721/how-to-use-bloomberg-data-history-bdh-command-within-microsoft-visual-basic-v?rq=1.

Comment: I've already checked that post. He uses the name of the asset and a precise date, not Excel cells

Comment: To use the cells, you would need to use the .address function and then get the letter and row number - ETF.Range(JD & Erw).address, here JD is the letter I want to use, and Erw is the end row.

Comment: Okay, so the line would look like to :


cells(I+1,3) = BDH(cells(i+1,1).address, "PX_LAST", cells(i+1,3).address, cells(I+1,3).address, "Period, Dates", "M,H")

Comment: Yeah did that not work? I use range instead of cells.

Comment: I think it should be cells(I+1,3).formula "= BDH(" & cells(i+1,1).address & ", ""PX_LAST""," & cells(i+1,3).address & "," & cells(I+1,3).address & ", ""Period, Dates"", ""M,H"")" but to be honest you probably want to have this more teased out, in terms of your code, your loop, etc.

Comment: Both don't really work...
For the first it does not recognize BDH as a function
For the second it says : "Compile error End of statement"

Comment: So maybe I should write BDH.function isn't ?

Comment: Why don't you use simple formulas instead of VBA? in C1: `=BDH(A1, "PX_LAST", B1, B1)` and drag the formula down?

Comment: No matter... when I try with Excel it tells me that the security is not valid
while  when I do it manually I find the price. So there must be something wrong..

Comment: Does it make a problem if I use the same start date and end date (for instance: 01/01/2015). So the formula would be: 

C1=BDH(A1,LAST_PRICE,B1,B1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If the ISIN is stored in cell A1 you can use this formula:

```
BDH(A1 & " ISIN", "PX_LAST", "8/25/2016", "8/25/2016")
```

You can also replace the dates with a reference to a cell that contains the date.